# Change background of switch to background image (css)

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

i wanted to add background image to my switch. i already change the circle background image when check or not. however i wanted to change the background image of the main switch container. can i ask how will i gonna do it? Thank you..

[image]
This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <style>
      .form-switch .form-check-input {
        width: 6em !important;
        height: 1.5em !important;
      }

      .form-switch .form-check-input:checked {
        background-image: url(https://img1.pnghut.com/12/19/25/wAke6Snm2D/icon-photography-digital-media-social-networking-service-mark-zuckerberg.jpg) !important;
      }
      .form-switch .form-check-input {
        background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/736x/2a/89/fe/2a89fee1a635745cec680e88efa49bcc.jpg) !important;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="form-check form-switch">
      <input
        class="form-check-input"
        type="checkbox"
        id="flexSwitchCheckChecked"
      />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckChecked">
        &emsp; Testing</label
      >
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-W8fXfP3gkOKtndU4JGtKDvXbO53Wy8SZCQHczT5FMiiqmQfUpWbYdTil/SxwZgAN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-skAcpIdS7UcVUC05LJ9Dxay8AXcDYfBJqt1CJ85S/CFujBsIzCIv+l9liuYLaMQ/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

You can access the code here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-butterfly-wql5c?file=/index.html:0-2150

Comment: What do you mean by main switch container? Is it the div surrounding input and label elements?

Comment: Hi i updated my question i added a picture and highlighted which part i want put background image. please guide me.

Comment: I took a look at it. You cannot do it like you wanted. You already have added image to input field and it is that Instagram image. Rest of the input field is actually colored by bootstrap's css styles. You will see what I mean if you add to .form-check-input background-size: auto; You should find either other Bootstrap component for this or create for yourself